# Explanation of this matrix differential equation

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, quadratic-forms

In one book I have found the equation:
$$ \bigtriangledown\cdot (De^{-irk(t)})=-k(t)^{T}Dk(t), $$
where k is a 3d vector, r=[x,y,z] and D is a 3x3 matrix.

I don't understand at all how to get the RHS from the LHS of the equation but it is crucial to understand some problem. Could you please explain me this? I would appreciate details.

It is eq. [6A.10] from "Diffusion MRI Theory, Methods, and Applications" by Derek K. Jones (2011), page 88.

Available here: https://books.google.pl/books?id=dbZCMePD52AC&pg=PA88&lpg=PA88&dq=darreck+diffusion+mri+page+the+resulting+ordinary+equation+for+M(t)&source=bl&ots=YK-JKOcEHo&sig=mFlcx5IVv6c6FBEsc0NIGtl13CE&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQ4pDCw7nZAhXIEywKHTkDCB0Q6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=darreck%20diffusion%20mri%20page%20the%20resulting%20ordinary%20equation%20for%20M(t)&f=false

Comment: Very weird.Is that a divergence on the LHS? That should be applied to a vector field, where is it? Also, LHS is a matrix while RHS is a scalar?

Comment: I am not sure, because there is many shortcuts. This equation is from book "Diffusion MRI Theory, Methods, and Applications" by Derek K. Jones (2011), page 88, equation [6A.10]

Comment: There is clearly a mistake in the book. In Equation (6.A7) there is $\nabla\cdot(D\nabla \psi)$ with $\psi =e^{irk}$, while in  Equation (6.A10) we see $\nabla\cdot(De^{irk})$ so the author forgot the gradient inside the parenthesis.

Comment: Indeed. However I still don't understand the solution.

Comment: have you seen the answer?

Comment: Now I've seen. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:
$$ \nabla \cdot (D\nabla\psi)= (-{\rm i})\nabla \cdot (D\psi \vec{k})=(-{\rm i})\sum_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(D\psi \vec{k})_i=(-{\rm i})\sum_{i,j} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}D_{ij}\psi  k_j$$

$$=-\sum_{i,j} D_{ij}\psi k_ik_j=-(k^TDk)\psi$$

Comment: However, this assumes $D$ does not depend on position.

Comment: Could you please explain what 'i' means in (D$\Psi k)_{i}$? and how exacly you transformed the two last terms in the first line?

Comment: the $i$ in $(D\psi k)_i$ is the $i$-th component of that vector (1st is $x$, 2nd is $y$, 3rd is $z$). I don't understand your other question. If you have difficulty with vector calculus, that is a different problem.

Comment: But why not just $(-{\rm i})\sum_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(D\psi \vec{k})$ ? It's gradient, right?

Comment: I just wrote the divergence explicitly in terms of coordinates to try to make it more clear. Are you now able to get to the final result on your own?

Comment: There is a divergence? Ok. I was confused because I assumed that it is a gradient. Now it schould be clear. Thanks!